# start multiple docker containers with a single command line shell script (without docker-compose)

Tags: bash, docker, sh

I've got 3 containers that will run on a single server, which we'll call: A,B,C

Each server has a script on the host that has the commands to start docker:

```
A_start.sh
B_start.sh
C_start.sh
```

I'm trying to create a swarm script to start them all, but not sure how.

```
ABC_start.sh
```

**UPDATE:** 
this seems to work, with the first being output to the terminal, cntrl+C exits out of them all.d

```
./A_start.sh & ./B_start.sh & ./C_start.sh
```

Answer (score 3):

1. swarm will not help you start them at all..., it is used to distribute the work amongst docker machines that are part of the cluster.
2. there is no good reason not to use `docker-compose` for that use case, its main purpose is to link containers properly, and bring them up, so your collection of scripts could end up being a single `docker-compose up` command.

Comment: if you are using swarm, then you may hit some of the limitations of `docker-compose`

Answer (score 0):

In bash,

you can do this:

```
nohup A_start.sh &
nohup B_start.sh &
nohup C_start.sh &
```